# beginner django setup: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings'

Tags: django, installation

I am trying to install django on ubuntu.  I am walking through the following setup tutorial:  http://jeffbaier.com/articles/installing-django-on-an-ubuntu-linux-server/

I am getting an error when I try to do the 'syncdb' step.  It seems like an environment problem.  How do I fix this?

```
me@ubuntu:~/django_projects/myproject$ django-admin.py syncdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 433, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  ...
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 92, in __init__
    raise ImportError("Could not import settings '%s' (Is it on sys.path?): %s" % (self.SETTINGS_MODULE, e))
ImportError: Could not import settings 'myproject.settings' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named myproject.settings
me@ubuntu:~/django_projects/myproject$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is a problem with that tutorial. You should run `manage.py syncdb`.

Answer (score 0):

or

```
django-admin.py syncdb --settings=myproject.settings
```

./manage.py is just a thin wrapper that every new django project is set up with to configure the path to that particular projects settings.py file.